Doesn't find files when building project
I have linked the SFML and TGUI libraries in my project. I also included these libraries in another CMakeLists in this project. When I start building the project, I get a message that the files from these libraries cannot be found. And every time it seems to be connected only with TGUI. I even tried using target_include_directories to include the library header files, but it didn't help. Additionally, this project lists both libraries in the search path header.
C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\ui\include\music_list.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp': No such file or directory
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\url_player.dir\build.make:75: CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:144: CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:123: url_player] Error 2

I know that libraries have been founded. Because I see the content of the message.
I include libraries like this:
set(SFML_DIR ${SFML_PATH})
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics REQUIRED PATHS ${SFML_DIR})

set(TGUI_DIR ${TGUI_PATH})
find_package(TGUI REQUIRED PATHS ${TGUI_DIR})

I try to include this files:
#include <TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp>
#include <TGUI/Widgets/Panel.hpp>

CmakeLists:
add_library(ui STATIC
        src/music_list.cpp
        src/button.cpp
        ui-config/src/json-ui-config.cpp
        src/menu.cpp
)

target_include_directories(ui PRIVATE ${TGUI_INCLUDE_DIR} include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/json ui-config/include)

target_link_libraries(ui PRIVATE tgui sfml-system sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-main music-storage json-storage)


I tried to clear the cache, reload the CMake project, relink libraries and recreate the class where the error occurs.
full commandline:
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player -BC:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 url_player
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player -BC:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles 11
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/all
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f storage\CMakeFiles\json-storage.dir\build.make storage/CMakeFiles/json-storage.dir/depend
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\storage C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\storage C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\storage\CMakeFiles\json-storage.dir\DependInfo.cmake "--color="
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f storage\CMakeFiles\json-storage.dir\build.make storage/CMakeFiles/json-storage.dir/build
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
[  9%] Linking CXX static library json-storage.lib
cd /d C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\storage && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\json-storage.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /d C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\storage && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\json-storage.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1440~1.338\bin\Hostx64\x64\lib.exe /nologo /machine:x64 /out:json-storage.lib @CMakeFiles\json-storage.dir\objects1.rsp 
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
[ 18%] Built target json-storage
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f music-storage\CMakeFiles\music-storage.dir\build.make music-storage/CMakeFiles/music-storage.dir/depend
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\music-storage C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\music-storage C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\music-storage\CMakeFiles\music-storage.dir\DependInfo.cmake "--color="
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f music-storage\CMakeFiles\music-storage.dir\build.make music-storage/CMakeFiles/music-storage.dir/build
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
[ 27%] Linking CXX static library music-storage.lib
cd /d C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\music-storage && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\music-storage.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /d C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\music-storage && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\music-storage.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1440~1.338\bin\Hostx64\x64\lib.exe /nologo /machine:x64 /out:music-storage.lib @CMakeFiles\music-storage.dir\objects1.rsp 
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
[ 36%] Built target music-storage
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f ui\CMakeFiles\ui.dir\build.make ui/CMakeFiles/ui.dir/depend
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\ui C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\ui C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\ui\CMakeFiles\ui.dir\DependInfo.cmake "--color="
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f ui\CMakeFiles\ui.dir\build.make ui/CMakeFiles/ui.dir/build
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
[ 45%] Linking CXX static library ui.lib
cd /d C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\ui && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\ui.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /d C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\ui && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\ui.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1440~1.338\bin\Hostx64\x64\lib.exe /nologo /machine:x64 /out:ui.lib @CMakeFiles\ui.dir\objects1.rsp 
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
[ 81%] Built target ui
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\url_player.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/depend
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\url_player.dir\DependInfo.cmake "--color="
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\url_player.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/build
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
[ 90%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/main.cpp.obj
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2024.1.4\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_cl_compile_depends --dep-file=CMakeFiles\url_player.dir\main.cpp.obj.d --working-dir=C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\cmake-build-debug --filter-prefix="Note: including file: " -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1440~1.338\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++17 -MDd -Zi /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\url_player.dir\main.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\url_player.dir/ /FS -c C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\main.cpp
main.cpp
C:\Users\vinog\CLionProjects\url-player\ui\include\music_list.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp': No such file or directory
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/vinog/CLionProjects/url-player/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\url_player.dir\build.make:78: CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:140: CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:147: CMakeFiles/url_player.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:126: url_player] Error 2


What is the value of TGUI_INCLUDE_DIR? Try printing it using message() command in CMake.

This works correctly and I get the path to the headers in the console

@Vinograd Then you need to show us the path that you get, and you also need to show us the path to the SFML-Graphics.hpp file that the compiler says it cannot find

@Vinograd This is not complicated, the compiler has list of locations to look, and you gave it a header file to find. There's really only three things that can go wrong 1) The file really isn't there 2) you gave the compiler the wrong location to look 3) you gave the compiler the wrong file to #include. That's all, you need to track down which of these has happened. Once you know that you can look further and figure out why things are wrong.

Add set(VERBOSE 1) to your CMake file and show us the full commandline, as well as the full path to that SFML-Graphics.hpp file.

You said that it is not complicated, but unfortunately I have no idea how to track it. I see that the libraries are connected, that the files exist on disk and that they are connected without problems without errors inside the code editor. But the error only occurs when building the project, and I don’t understand how to track it, because I see the existence of the file.
You asked for output to the control:  TGUI_INCLUDE_DIR: C:/libs/TGUI/include

@Vinograd So there is a file C:/libs/TGUI/include/TGUI/Backend/SFML-Graphics.hpp? Assuming there is then the next thing to do would be to find out what options are being passed by cmake to the compiler. There's a cmake verbose mode I think, that should tell you that.

@Botje The full path is C:\libs\TGUI\include\TGUI\Backend

I updated my question with console output.

Thanks. The full CMake output made it clear that there was nothing wrong with your ui target but with a different target (that you did not show)

Yes, the problem is that you added TGUI_INCLUDE_DIR as PRIVATE which means it only applies to the ui target, not the other target where the build fails.

The problem is with your url_player target, not the ui target.
You passed PRIVATE to the target_include_directories command, which means that url_player does not receive the include paths you set up for ui.
Either change the PRIVATE to PUBLIC (so it does get propagated) or add an explicit
target_include_directories(url_player PRIVATE ${TGUI_INCLUDE_DIR})

Also, look into modern CMake, where the include directories are part of the TGUI library target and you just link to it instead of setting up include directories separately.

Thanks, it works, BUT! I included the libraries via find_package(), but I still had to include the headers as directories. Why?
set(TGUI_DIR ${TGUI_PATH})
find_package(TGUI REQUIRED PATHS ${TGUI_DIR})
I have these lines written in root CMake

Because find_package is only responsible for defining targets and/or setting some variables. It is your responsibility to use the provided targets/variables in your own targets.

I'm sorry, but I'm not a professional, could you tell me exactly what you meant here:
Also, look into modern CMake, where the include directories are part of the TGUI library target and you just link to it instead of setting up include directories separately.

See Modern CMake, Effective Modern CMake and It's Time To Do CMake Right
